# Como juntar a pontuação com a última palavra a esquerda?

Tags: python, python-3.x

pode parecer uma dúvida boba, mas realmente não encontrei resposta em minhas leituras. Criei um programinha cuja finalidade é calcular o meu Coeficiente de Rendimento e o percentual do curso concluído na faculdade, cujo código segue abaixo:

```
x = open('carto.txt')
cred = []
nota = []
sit = []
cr = 0
sumcred = 0
totcred = 244 #Total de créditos do curso.
aux = 0
for line in x:
    a = line.split(" ")
    cred += [int(a[0])]
    nota += [float(a[1])]
    sit += [(a[2])]
for i in range(len(nota)):
    sit[i] = sit[i].strip()
    if sit[i] not in {"Isento"}:
        sumcred += (cred[i]) #Calcula o somatório dos créditos cursados até o momento.
for i in range(len(nota)):
    sit[i] = sit[i].strip()
    if sit[i] in {"aprovado", "Isento"}:
        aux += (cred[i]) #Calcula o somatório dos créditos nas matérias onde se obteve aprovação ou isenção.
for i in range(len(cred)):
    sit[i] = sit[i].strip()
    if sit[i] not in {"Isento"}:
        cr += cred[i]*nota[i] #Faz a multiplicação da nota obtida em cada disciplina pela quantidade de créditos (desconsidera isenções).
print("O seu coeficiente de rendimento acumulado (CR) é igual a:",(round((cr/sumcred),2)))
print("O total de créditos do seu curso é de:",totcred,"créditos")
print("O total de créditos cursados até o momento é de:",aux,"créditos")
b = aux/totcred #Calcula o percentual concluído do curso.
print("O percentual concluído até o momento é de:",(round((b*100),2)),"%")
if b == 1:
    print("Parabéns, você concluiu o seu curso!")
```

O programa roda corretamente e fornece a saída que consta na imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que na última linha, onde está escrito `O percentual concluído até o momento é de: 53.69 %` o símbolo de percentual (%) está separado do número a sua esquerda.

Pergunta: Como faço para juntar o `%` com o `53.69`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa separação que você vê com espaços acontece porque o `print` foi feito separando cada valor com virgula, ou seja invocando print com vários valores:

```
print("O percentual concluído até o momento é de:",(round((b*100),2)),"%")
#                                                 ^--                ^--
```

Para controlar a impressão de forma exata o ideal é interpolar os valores na string final. Pode fazer isto utilizando `format` assim:

```
print("O percentual concluído até o momento é de:{}%".format(round(b*100,2)))
```

Repare que o valor é colocado no local onde tem os `{}`. Por isso você pode construir a string com quantos valores quiser e nos locais que pretender.

Também pode utilizar [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) se estiver a trabalhar com python 3.6+:

```
print(f"O percentual concluído até o momento é de:{round(b*100,2)}%")
```

Answer (score 2):

Altere a linha:

```
print("O percentual concluído até o momento é de:",(round((b*100),2)),"%")
```

para:

```
print("O percentual concluído até o momento é de:",str(round((b*100),2))+"%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Atribuí a variável e fiz *cast*.

Testei assim e deu certo.

> > > `a="Teste com valor d:"`
> > >
> > > `b=round((17.45*4.987),2)`
> > >
> > > `c=str(b)`
> > >
> > > `d=c + "%"`
> > >
> > > `print (a,d)`

`Teste com valor d: 87.02%`

Talvez te ajude.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição para o stackoverflow. No entanto, Python é uma lingugaem que permite várias formas de compor uma string com interpolação de valores, e mesmo a função print permite controle do espaçamento entre itens -  A sua proposta então, apesar de funcionar, não é a melhor forma de resolver esse problema específico.